# GWT - IncompatibleRemoteServiceException

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I am passing a `HashMap<String, Object>` to the server. STRING contains the parameter name and OBJECT is a string array. I am getting the following exception. 
I am using GWT(2.5) and hibernate-core-4.2.9 final.

> An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: metric1

I am passing the following parameters to the service,

```
UIParam<String, Object> param = new UIParam<String, Object>();

param.put("metric", new String[]{"metric1"});

param.put("attribute", new String[]{"attribute1"});
service.getData(param, callback);
```

Please help!!

Comment: what does it means `.ClassNotFoundException: num_active_queries` what is `num_active_queries` here in your code?

Comment: If Object is a String array, why do you pass Object?

Comment: can you show UIParam class?

Comment: @Braj - edited my question, num_active_queries is the element passed inside the String array

Comment: @mudalov - UIParam is a class that implements Serializable and a map field - Map<K, V> map.

Comment: @Andrei - I am passing Object because this map is used throughout my application and needs to handle different types of data types

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, this is due to the usage of Object, it's not serializable thus GWT cannot find the matching service